# in Laravel 5, in the share method, how can I return indexes to the view if I pass an array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have this data

```
$data["isLoggedIn"] = true;
$data["isAdmin"] = true;
$data["isOrg"] = true;
```

and I share the data to the view this way.

```
view()->share('data', $this->data);
```

In my view (blade) I access the data like

```
{{ $data['isAdmin'] }}
```

I would like to be get the data with the key, something like:

```
{{ $isAdmin }}
```

Do I need to make a foreach array and pass each inner key?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share an array directly with this syntax using the View facade:

```
View::share( $this->data );
```

Now you can access any key like this:

```
{{ $key }}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer is NO. You don't have to pass those data using `foreach` loop. You can do this by the following way:

In controller:

```
$data["isLoggedIn"] = true;
$data["isAdmin"] = true;
$data["isOrg"] = true;
return view('your_view', $data);
```

On the other hand, To share those data in all views globally you have to do something like this in controller:

```
View::share('isLoggedIn', true);
View::share('isAdmin', true);
View::share('isOrg', true);
return view('your_view');
```

To do this you need to write `use View;` at the top of the controller.

In blade:(e.g. yourview.blade.php):

```
{{ $isAdmin }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you share a named array, to get the data with the key you can try

```
$isLoggedIn = true;
$isAdmin = true;
$isOrg = true;
view()->share('isLoggedIn', $this->$isLoggedIn)->share('isAdmin', $this->$isAdmin)->share('isOrg', $this->isOrg);
```

or you can send the data as flash data

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data